# Data Validation: Do not allow entries like "123%"

Tags: excel

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent cell entries based on this examples.

- 123 = Allow
- 123%= Not Allow
- %   = Not Allow

Though 123% is interpreted as 123, which does not affect the computation, I was wondering if the above is possible.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: @avrahamcool I know the problem is moot since the value is still the same. I am wondering if it can be solved but if it will cause more problems, I would just explain to my client.

Comment: Should 12.3 be allowed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Format the cell as general and in Data Validation - Custom write the formula:

```
=LEFT(CELL("format";A1))<>"P"
```

Assuming, in this case, you want to apply it to cell A1

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

If "%" alone as text is not allowed then use this as formula instead:

```
=NOT(OR(LEFT(CELL("format";A1))="P";ISNUMBER(FIND("%";A1)))
```